# iPod Touch 5: Start new messages field doesn't show up

Tags: ios, ipod

http://i57.tinypic.com/30kysfl.jpp

Hi, my iPod Touch 5th gen dosent have the start new messages field, and its not there when I scroll down. Also, my iPhone's phone number wasn't an option when the field was there, only my emails.

Answer (score 1):

Is iMessage activated on your iPhone?
Is your iPhone and iPod signed in with the same Apple ID and connected to the Internet?
Without activating iMessage on your phone with the same Apple ID you can't use the telephone number on your iPod.

If you can't use the phone number for iMessage on your iPhone, then try with turning iMessage off from the settings and turn it on again a few seconds later. Try doing that on the iPod as well.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you've not already done troubleshooting on your own, and assuming that the iPod is not provisioned in any way, here are steps that I would try in order until the issue is resolved. Be sure you have your Apple ID password handy or memorized:

> 1. Make sure that the same Apple ID is being used for iMessage as on your iPhone and on your iPod. If either is different, log into the
>      Apple ID that you'd like to use on both devices. Otherwise, it will
>      not work. (I know this is obvious.)
> 2. On iPod, toggle iMessage off and then on from Settings > Messages.
> 3. On iPod, log in and out of Apple ID from Messages menu.
> 4. On iPhone, toggle iMessage off then on.
> 5. On iPhone, log in and out of Apple ID from Messages menu.
> 6. On iPod, go to Settings > General > Reset, and choose "Reset All Settings." This does not erase any data, but does reset background
>      images, Location Services, and Wi-Fi passwords.

If the last step still doesn't resolve the issue, it may be affecting iOS, in which case I recommend [backing the iPod up to iTunes or iCloud](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT203977), then [using iTunes to restore (erase the device and reinstall iOS)](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201252).